# Space complexities of 2d array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, space, space-complexity

I am currently in my final year studying data structures and algorithms as a course. And I was asked a question ( calculate the space complexity of an algorithm traversing a 2d array holding double data type) and I am stuck unfortunately. I know the formula for calculating space complexity is (data type x no of inputs) + (data type × no of outputs) but I have never come across this type of question till now. Google keeps confusing me more than I already am. If anyone knows this I'll appreciate the help.

Comment: Mh, you know the formula. What is the problem then ? Why don't you apply it ?

Comment: Traversing a 2d array can hardly be called an *algorithm*. Algorithms solve problems. What is the problem solved by traversing the 2d array? What are the variables of the input? Is the 2d array *square*? Is it represented as a nested array? Are the subarrays all of the same length? ...What is the algorithm supposed to produce as output?